# How can I make a C# class instantiate another class in its constructor?

Tags: c#

I created the following:

```
public class HttpStatusErrors
{
    public HttpStatusErrors()
    {
        this.Details = new List<HttpStatusErrorDetails>();
    }
    public string Header { set; get; }
    public IList<HttpStatusErrorDetails> Details { set; get; }
}

public class HttpStatusErrorDetails
{
    public HttpStatusErrorDetails()
    {
        this.Errors = new List<string>();
    }
    public string Error { set; get; }
    public IList<string> Errors { set; get; }
}
```

In my code I am using it like this:

```
var msg = new HttpStatusErrors();
   msg.Header  = "Validation Error";           
   foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors) {

      msg.Details. // Valid so far 
      msg.Details.Error // Gives the error below:
```

The Ide recognizes msg.Details as being valid but when I try to write the second line I get:

```
Error   3   'System.Collections.Generic.IList<TestDb.Models.Http.HttpStatusErrorDetails>' 
does not contain a definition for 'Error' and no extension method 'Error' accepting a first 
argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<TestDb.Models.Http.HttpStatusErrorDetails>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    
C:\K\ST136 Aug 16\WebUx\Controllers\ProblemController.cs    121 33  WebUx
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I thought the way I had this set up that new Lists would be created when the first class was created.

Comment: You're trying to assign a value of a single variable to a List. This cannot be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`msg.Details` returns a `List` object. `List<T>` does not have an `Errors` property. You need to access a specific element in your list, and only then will you have your `Errors` property.

For example:

```
msg.Details[0].Error
```

In your code you might want to make sure that `msg.Details` contains elements before trying to access them, or better yet iterate over them in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Jason No idea, especially seeings as it's the right answer. Should probably check that `Details` isn't empty before accessing the element, though.

Comment: @Jason I guess someone didn't understand the question/answer.

Comment: Btw, OP tries to access the `Error` not the `Errors` property, both exist ;)

Answer (score 0):

Details is a collection. The property `Error` belongs to an item in the collection Details. There is no property `Error` on that collection Details

Answer (score 0):

you are tying to go to `Details` which is a `IList<HttpStatusErrorDetails>`.

if you want to go through the items in that list u need go over them
for example

```
msg.Details[number].Errors
```

or

```
foreach(HttpStatusErrorDetails err in msg.Details)
{
    err.Errors
}
```